# Python: reshape dataframe based on dates using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have the following data frame which I want to group according to the event it took place:

```
id diagnoses diagnoses_date medication medication_date
1  A         2015-04-12     Y          2017-06-06
1  B         2018-02-05     Y          2017-06-06
2  B         2015-07-03     Z          2014-04-04
2  B         2015-07-03     Y          2016-06-05
```

it should look something like the following:

```
id diagnoses_0 medication_0 diagnoses_1 medication_1
1  A           Y            B           NA
2  NA          Z            B           Y
```

I don't even know where to start. Any comments much appreciated.

Cheers,

Andres

Comment: Why `diagnose_0` of `id 2` is `NA`? shouldn't it be `B` as in the data? Same question for `medication_1` of `id 1`.

Comment: great answer, because there was a medication that took place before